# Cannot implicitly convert type string to microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variable

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to store a String inside a Dts variable in visual c# / visual c sharp. But, I get the error below. How do I fix this ? I have not used C# before so its hard for me to figure out. I do know Java well though.

```
        String v = Dts.Variables["myVar1"].Value + "";
        String x = Dts.Variables["myVar2"].Value + v + "'";
        Dts.Variables["myVar2"] = SQL;  // Why do I get an error here ?
```

The errors are -

Error   1   Property or indexer 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.this[object]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable'

Comment: How is this vb.net ? It is visual C#

Comment: Until your edit it said Visual Basic in the first sentence.  Unfortunately I didn't go over the code snippet to try to figure out which language it is.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin - Looks like you really live up to your name. Okay, I made a mistake. Id did use C# in my second sentence though. Can I get my one back ?

Comment: I'm saying that I made a mistake - the code is C#, and you say C# in the second sentence.  The C# tag has been edited back in for over an hour now, so any change I made has been undone.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin - Can you give me + 1 now ?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I wasn't the downvoter, I don't think a downvote was fair in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the reference [Dts.Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.aspx) is a collection of [Variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variable.aspx) elements and thus you cannot assign a string to a element of this collection. (and, as another answer pointed out, this collection is readonly)

Probably you want

```
Dts.Variables["myVar2"].Value = SQL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the first error is that the `Variables[]` indexer is read-only. That is you can only read the value of `Dts.Variables["myVar2"]` from it and not assign a new value to replace it. The indexer is essentially a syntactic shortcut for invoking a function on the `Variables` collection.

The second error stems from the fact that you are trying to assign a `String` type value to the previously mentioned indexer which returns an object of type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable`. Again, it's the incorrect use of the indexer that is really prompting the second error.

The proper way to access the value of the variable object returned by the indexer is via the `.Value` property, the same as you are doing on the first line in your sample code:

```
Dts.Variables["myVar2"].Value = SQL;
```

Comment: so, will that put the value of SQL into "myVar2" ?